# Change record values - haskell

Tags: haskell, record

I have this record:

```
data Ship = CShip {Planet::String}
    deriving Show
spaceship = CShip {Planet = "alphaCentauriBb"}
```

but I want to change the String on Planet. for example:

```
Planet = "alphaCentauriCc"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the record update syntax to update the value of a field. This will create a new record value with the same field values as the old ones except for the updated fields.

```
newSpaceship = spaceship {planet = "alphaCentauriCc"}
```

Note that field names must be lowercase.

Comment: thanks! so I can't change the values on spaceship, It is a must to create a new one, right?

Comment: @Nahu: all variables are immutable in Haskell so *yes*. You can work with an `IORef` to reference to something and use `IO` to update the object to what it refers. But then still the *reference* is immutable, and using IO would make the variables it wraps mutable, which is probably not a good idea.